# Publish SPD List Workflow to all subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, list-workflow

**SharePoint Online:** We have created one list workflow in SharePoint designer and published it in one subsite.
But now we want to publish/deploy this workflow to same list (eg: Requests) in all subsites.

How to achieve this using **JSOM** OR **CSOM** OR **Powershell**?

Comment: why don't you go for reusable workflow?

Comment: List workflow is our requirement.